# Remove index when writing a dataframe to tex file

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I have a dataframe that i read using pd.ExcelFile()

Iam doing like :

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('input.xlsx')
df = pd.parse()
latexFormat = df.to_latex()
```

Now i write `latexFormat`to a .tex file, by simply opening a file in write mode and then doing `fid.write(latexFormat)`
But it also includes indexes.

How do i remove indexes when writing it to tex file (or) i need to make changes to dataFrame before using `to_latex()`

Answer (score 5):

Add `index=False`, e.g.,

```
latexFormat = df.to_latex(index=False)
```

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Actuallly i have numbers in range of $10^{26}$ in one column of dataFrame. I want to write them as strings in .tex format. like 10e+12. How do i do this ?

Comment: You may use string format to archive this. For exmaple, `'{.2e}'.format(1e12)` will output `'1.00e+12'`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the parameter `index=False`

```
latexFormat = df.to_latex(index=False)
```